# How to spawn a named, enchanted, unbreakable sword?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a map based of a simulation world and I am trying to build an OP sword for myself as a test runner. I have part of the command, I just need help sticking the `{Unbreakable:1}` into the command

Current command:

```
/Give Hydrotronics diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name"Valkyrie's Lance",Lore:[The Ragnite Hums As The Lance Rests In Your Hands]},ench:[{Id:16,Lvl:200},{Id:19,Lvl:3},{Id:20,Lvl:13},{Id:20,Lvl:13},{Id:17,Lvl:30},{Id:34,Lvl:10}]}
```

I tried removing `Id:34` (Unbreaking) and replacing it with `{Unbreakble:1}` but the Unbreakable didn't come through.

Comment: Have you tried it in a command block? /Give @a diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name"Valkyrie's Lance",Lore:[The Ragnite Hums As The Lance Rests In Your Hands]},ench:[{Id:16,Lvl:200},{Id:19,Lvl:3},{Id:20,Lvl:13},{Id:20,Lvl:13},{Id:17,Lvl:30},{Id:34,Lvl:10}]}

Comment: The command is impossible without command blocks, chat window is not large enough

Comment: It should be. This is a code for a vanilla 'mod': http://pastebin.com/uG2HU01x That can fit into a command block

Comment: No the command block size is fine! I'm talking about when you hit T, the chat input isn't large enough for one to put in the command, so you HAVE to use a command block

Comment: Ahh no I get you now sorry, It was late at night then and I was half-asleep xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see that your problem is to get the Unbreakable correct.

This is how you can make something Unbreakable, without the enchantments.

`/give Hydrotronics minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,ench:`

After that `,ench:`, you can place all the enchantments you want. Lore Text and other things can also be put in.

If you need a guideline, you can find [Minecraft Give Generators](http://ezekielelin.com/give/) to build the commands for you.

Comment: Thx, i'll give it a go

Comment: OK it works, thx!

Comment: no probelm :d hehe

Answer (score 1):

The "Unbreakable" tag is a completely seperate tag from enchantments and belongs in the sword's root json node (inside only the outer set of curly braces). This is not the only problem with your command. The command will not execute first of all because Minecraft commands are case sensitive (the stupidest thing that could be fixed easily but Mojang decides not to) and must be lowercase (changed "Give" to "give"). JSON parsing will fail because there is no semicolon ':' between "Name" and "Valkyrie's Lance". The enchantments are all invalid (and show up as Protection level 0) because of capitalization (caps problems in JSON tags are not a bug, make sure you are using the correct tags and tag capitalization when creating a JSON object. Use the Minecraft Wiki's [Chunk Format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format) page for block/entity related NBT tags and the [Player.dat Format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format) page for item related NBT tags. Also you had duplicate Fire Aspect enchantments (removed 1)

A correction for your current command would be:
`/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Valkyrie's Lance",Lore:[The Ragnite Hums As The Lance Rests In Your Hands]},ench:[{id:16,lvl:200},{id:19,lvl:3},{id:20,lvl:13},{id:17,lvl:30}],Unbreakable:true}`

Comment: Eh, I typed this on a phone, I'm missing a few keys... But the colons ect. Are all in the original command, as I have spawned it in multiple times, like to kill the enderdragon to build in end. Also, my phone forced me to do Id or it will change it to I'd which is really annoying. That's why it has Id. The cases are all correct in the command block itself :)

Comment: Ah okey makes sense now :} (disable autocorrect, it will ruin your life)

Comment: XD if only, this bloody phone is hiding the off button for autocorrect from me!

Answer (score -5):

As detonation said, you can put {Unbreakable:1,ench... to make it. For example, (Change this if you want)
give @p minecraft:diamond_axe 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,ench:[,{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:1000}],display:{Name:"Midnight",Lore:["Forged by many gods in an attempt to stop a great evil. It is yours now, use it wisely."]}}

Comment: This doesn't add anything that wasn't already said.